# pyramid on apache/mod_wsgi : ImportError: No module named registry

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I am a very new pyramid learner, I just followed the documentation for creating a new pyramid project : I succeeded to install a virtualenv with pyramid 1.5 packages and run the project in developement mode with 'pserve'.

But, when using apache + mod_wsgi, this is another story : I got this error into the apache error log :

```
    [Fri May 02 09:08:53 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/eric/perso/projects/Pyratest/pyramid.wsgi", line 8, in <module>
    [Fri May 02 09:08:53 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
...
    [Fri May 02 09:08:53 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/eric/perso/projects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg/pyramid/threadlocal.py", line 3, in <module>
    [Fri May 02 09:08:53 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from pyramid.registry import global_registry
    [Fri May 02 09:08:53 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/eric/perso/projects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg/pyramid/registry.py", line 5, in <module>
    [Fri May 02 09:08:53 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from zope.interface.registry import Components
    [Fri May 02 09:08:53 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named registry
```

I added a sys.path dump into my pyramid.wsgi :

```
import sys

print "=" * 80
for p in sys.path:
    print p

from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging

ini_path = '/home/eric/perso/projects/Pyratest/production.ini'
setup_logging(ini_path)
application = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```

I can see that the path to zope/interface/registry.py is reachable for the apache user.
This path is at the very beginning of the sys.path, so there should not have a path conflict somewhere.

My apache virtualhost definition :

```
Listen 9999
NameVirtualHost localhost:9999
<VirtualHost localhost:9999>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/pyramid-test-error.log

        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/pyramid-test-access.log combined
        ServerSignature On

        Alias /static/ /home/eric/perso/projects/Pyratest/pyratest/static/
        <Location "/static/">
                <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
                AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/javascript
                </IfModule>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Location>

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid-test user=eric group=eric processes=4 threads=1 python-path=/home/eric/perso/projects/Pyratest/:/home/eric/perso/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup pyramid-test
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/eric/perso/projects/Pyratest/pyramid.wsgi

        <Directory /home/eric/perso/projects/venv>
                WSGIProcessGroup eric
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I run manually the venv python interpreter, I can import zope.interface.registry without any problem. I do not understand why with mod_wsgi, it does not work.
I tried many times, by creating many venv and populating by using easy_install only or pip only, with or without --no-site-packages, I have taken the latest version of virtualenv,distribute,pip, setuptools, but still the same problem. Only one constant : only zope.interface.registry seems to be unreachable : why this one and not other pyramid packages ?

**UPDATE 1 :** The registry.py and .pyc are readable :

```
eric@pcubuntu:~/perso/projects$ . ./venv/bin/activate
(venv)eric@pcubuntu:~/perso/projects$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zope.interface.registry
>>> print zope.interface.registry.__file__
/home/eric/perso/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/registry.pyc
>>> 

(venv)eric@pcubuntu:~/perso/projects$ ls /home/eric/perso/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/registry.pyc
/home/eric/perso/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/registry.pyc
(venv)eric@pcubuntu:~/perso/projects$ ls -la /home/eric/perso/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/registry.pyc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 eric eric 25127 mai    2 08:54 /home/eric/perso/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/registry.pyc
(venv)eric@pcubuntu:~/perso/projects$ ls -la /home/eric/perso/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/registry.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 eric eric 18877 mai    2 08:54 /home/eric/perso/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/registry.py
```

**Update 2:** here are the installed packages :

```
(venv)eric@pcubuntu:~/perso/projects/venv$ pip freeze
Chameleon==2.15
Mako==0.9.1
MarkupSafe==0.21
PasteDeploy==1.5.2
Pygments==1.6
Pyratest==0.0
WebOb==1.3.1
argparse==1.2.1
pyramid==1.5
pyramid-chameleon==0.1
pyramid-debugtoolbar==2.0.2
pyramid-mako==1.0.2
repoze.lru==0.6
translationstring==1.1
venusian==1.0a8
waitress==0.8.8
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.deprecation==4.1.1
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

**Update 3** : I finally found a way to start pyramid, but it is so weird that I cannot consider that as a solution :

```
- use pip install instead of easy_install
- add "import pip" at the top of the pyramid.wsgi file    (!!!)
```

**Update 4** : I Redo the exact procedure of the documentation here [Running a Pyramid Application under mod_wsgi](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/modwsgi/index.html), that is : a modwsgi directory, a virtualenv within and finally Pyratest within virtualenv : still the same thing : does not work with apache mod_wsgi : ImportError: No module named registry

**Update 5** : I decided to install from scratch a brand new ubuntu 12.04 by using vagrant, by this way, everything is working fine. So the question is why it does not work on my usual desktops : for both, it does not work... I run Django on them without any problem, may be there are some tunings that conflict with pyramid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way :

The problem was : mod_wsgi do not provide the same sys.path as python in virtualenv.
To fix that I added at the top of the pyramid.wsgi :

```
import sys
sys.path = [
    '/home/eric/perso/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
]


activate_this = '/home/eric/perso/projects/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Comment: Damn ... it's ugly  as hell, but I've just run into this myself and had to apply a similar horrid hack to get things working again (even after rebuilding the venv); incidentally in my case the project was already under the venv, and I'd already followed the guide to running Pyramid under mod_wsgi. Many thanks for posting a solution (although I'd certainly like to find a cleaner one!)

Comment: Looks like there is a [slightly cleaner option](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html) but it depends on a more recent version of mod_wsgi than I've currently got

Answer (score 1):

In case you have not yet read it, there is an official tutorial for [Running a Pyramid Application under mod_wsgi](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/modwsgi/index.html).

Comment: That was the documentation I used  :(

Answer (score 0):

What do you get for:

```
import zope.interface.registry
print(zope.interface.registry.__file__)
```

when run in command line Python?

In other words, where does it actually exist?

And what version of mod_wsgi are you using?

---

UPDATE 1

You say based on `__file__` it exists under:

```
/home/eric/perso/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

yet the `site-packages` directory you add to `python-path` option to the `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive does not match and instead uses:

```
/home/eric/perso/projects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Maybe you should make the directory given to `python-path` match.

Comment: Yes, of course the file exists. In addition, as I said, it is readable by mod_wsgi apache user.

Comment: mod_wsgi version : 3.3 (the latest on ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: Unfortunately, I already noticed that. virtualenv generate symbolic links from local/lib/* to lib/* : so venv/local/lib and venv/lib are equivalent. In addition only zope.interface.repository has got a problem not the others that are using the same python-path

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo : I meant zope.interface.registry

Answer (score 0):

After reading [these guidelines](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_WSGIScriptAlias_Directive) I would recommend to move your python project Pyratest into your virtualenv.

```
home/eric/perso/projects/venv/Pyratest/
```

This could solve several issues regarding permissions. This way mod_wsgi **Directory** directive applies to your python project **AND** your virtualenv. This directory layouts complies with referenced pyramid cookbook article and common pyramid scaffold usage. Your current mod_wsgi setup only applies to virtualenv, not to your Pyratest directory.

I further changed WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIProcessGroup to `pyramid` to comply with cookbook article. According to your `pip freeze` your own package Pyratest was installed in virtualenv using `python setup.py develop`. Thus we only have to pass a single directory to `python-path` argument. Now this setup looks similar to the one in the cookbook. Make sure `apache user` and `eric` can get into these directories as well.

```
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=eric group=eric processes=4 threads=1 python-path=/home/eric/perso/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/eric/perso/projects/venv/Pyratest/pyramid.wsgi

    <Directory /home/eric/perso/projects/venv>
            WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

My recommendation would be to start from scratch by creating a new venv. After you got, repeat it again to be sure your assumptions work. Good luck

For further debugging purposes I recommend [mod_wsgi basic docs](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration-guides/running-a-basic-application.html#mounting-the-wsgi-application) to build a mod_wsgi setup step-by-step.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already noticed that. virtualenv generate symbolic links from local/lib/* to lib/* : so venv/local/lib and venv/lib are equivalent. In addition only zope.interface.repository has got a problem not the others that are using the same python-path

Comment: What wrong with zope.interface.repository? You mean zope.interface.registry??? Please explain!

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo : I meant zope.interface.registry

Comment: virtualenv should not be chaining off another site-packages directory unless you are using an ancient virtualenv or explicitly using --site-packages option. So something doesn't seem right there.

Comment: I use all latest virtualenv, setuptools etc..
And I use --no-site-package as documented in pyramid documentation

Comment: I do not understand Graham latest comment. Graham, please explain. Besides that I edited my answer regarding python-path argument. Please consider changes.

Comment: I redo step by step the pyramid documentation and I checked pathes and unix rights : still the same problem. pserve : OK but not apache + mod_wsgi : ImportError: No module named registry